# Best way to implement permissions based on user type

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

In Django, I have a model Artists, and a custom User model with a `UserManager` class:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Creates and saves a new user"""

        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)  # required for supporting multiple databases

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        """Creates and saves a new superuser"""
        user = self.create_user(email, password)
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """Custom user model that supports using email instead of username"""

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
```

I want superusers, staff users, and the artist themselves to be able to edit the artist model. What is the best way to do this?

I'm thinking of adding a field to my artist model like so:

```
users_who_can_edit = models.ManyToManyField(user=get_user_model())
```

but I'm guessing I implement a filter in the view?

Answer (score 0):

That approach sounds like it will work, and it allows for the possibility of an artist being associated with multiple users, and vice versa.

Are you planning to edit using the built in Django admin, or building your own edit view?  That will affect the detail of how to do it?